# R function not generating desired output

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

```
box(853, title = "No of Employees", width = 2, height = "155px", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, id = "empid")
```

produces

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="box box-solid box-primary" style="height: 155px">
    <div class="box-header">
      <h3 class="box-title">No of Employees</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body" id="empid">853</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may see a `class = "box-title"` is generated.

I want to create a new function, where I want to fix width, height, status and solidheader

So I created one,

```
vas_metric_box <- function(..., title, w = 2, h = "155px", id = NULL){
  box(..., title, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", width = w, height = h, id = id)
}
```

which produces

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="box box-solid box-primary" style="height: 155px">
    <div class="box-body" id="empid">
      853
      No of Employees
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question**

1) How can I produce box title in my code.
2) I am using same code in my function, why are there difference between both approaches?

Comment: Have you tried `title = title` when you call `box` inside your `vas_metric_box` ?

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you pass `title` when calling `box` inside `vas_metric_box` is not interpreted correctly by `box`. Write like this:

```
vas_metric_box <- function(..., title, w = 2, h = "155px", id = NULL){
  box(..., title = title, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", width = w, height = h, id = id)
}
```